# GWT 2.0 Eclipse plugin - how to automatically launch browser on run / debug?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, google-eclipse-plugin

I've downloaded the new [GTW 2.0](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html) and it's [eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/eclipse/index.html)

In the new eclipse plugin, when running or debugging instead of opening the browser, it shows this:

> For your convenience, here are some URLs that you may wish to view in development mode. Simply copy/paste a URL below into any supported browser.

At least they could have made the URL clickable (e.g. open your default browser) but you can only copy.

Is there a patent infringment they are trying to avoid? whats so hard in opening a browser link?

Comment: I think that's just how it is now, it doesn't bother me all that much. Have you tried filing a bug report/feature request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems they don't support it for some reason, there is no workaround, and it is the [intended way](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0.html).

[image: Development Mode]

> Notice that your launch configuration
>   is listed in the view, along with some
>   suggested URLs to start up your GWT
>   application. Copy the URL for your
>   application into the browser's address
>   bar by selecting the entry and
>   choosing Copy from the context menu.
>   Once you have navigated to the startup
>   URL in your browser, you'll notice
>   that a browser entry will be added to
>   the launch configuration:

If anyone from Google reads this, it would be nice to explain why on earth you don't launch the URL?

Comment: I don't want it to.  I've got a browser up and running, with the URLs set the way I want them.  I don't need Eclipse messing around with that in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Strange. I haven't looked at this stuff since GWT 1.8 or so, but at that time my favorite browser would pop right up when the app was launched.

I don't know exactly what's wrong in your case, but I'd check the following:

- Does (double) clicking on a `.html` file in a file browser (Explorer or whatever you use) cause a browser to open up?
- What about <s>double clicking</s>"Run as..." on a `.jsp` file in Eclipse? For me, that fires up Firefox, regardless of GWT. You may want to set up a file association in Eclipse to make this work.

Comment: 1 - yes, and 2 - really? the default is opening it in the JSP editor, isn't it?  anyways, please try the new plugin and you'll see what I mean... (btw, I just realized this is Jack Nicholson in The Shining and not you)

Comment: My bad - in Eclipse, what I meant was, can you do "Run as..." on a HTML or JSP file and have browser opening up? And yeah, I'm batsh%t crazy so I thought that picture suits me.

Comment: Yes, doing Run as... (the only valid option is "GWT Application")renders the above message, no browser is opening up... (I'm sure its intentional)

Comment: Sorry then, I'm out of ideas. I can't spare the time right now to install 2.0 and check this out for myself :( Good luck!